# Trying to prove directly that the Laplacian is closed.

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, laplacian

I am trying to prove directly that the Laplacian operator is closed on its maximal set. I have the following with some doubts.

Considering the operator $-\Delta$ defined on $D(-\Delta)=\left\{u\in L^2: -\Delta u\in L^2\right\}$, let $(u_n)\subset D(-\Delta)$ such that $u_n\to u$ in $L^2$, $-\Delta u_n\to v$ for some $v\in L^2$. The operator will be closed if $u\in D(-\Delta)$ and $-\Delta u=v$.

By triangle inequality, $\left\|u\right\|_{2}\leq \left\|u-u_n\right\|_{2}+\left\|u_n\right\|_{2}$, then $\left\|u\right\|_{2}\leq \lim_n \left\|u_n\right\|_{2}$. Assuming that the limit exists, we would have $u\in L^2$.

**Question 1**. Is there a limit $\lim_n \left\|u_n\right\|_{2}$?

Similarly, I run into the same difficulty proving that $-\Delta u\in L^2$ as $\left\|-\Delta u\right\|_{2}\leq \left\|-\Delta(u-u_n)\right\|_{2}+\left\|-\Delta u_n\right\|_{2}$.

Also, $\left\|-\Delta u-v\right\|_{2}\leq \left\|-\Delta(u-u_n)\right\|_{2}+\left\|-\Delta u_n-v\right\|_{2}$.

**Question 2**. Is it valid $\left\|-\Delta(u-u_n)\right\|_{2}\leq \left\|-\Delta\right\|\left\|u-u_n \right\|_{2}$?

Thank you.

**Actualization**. Apparently, $-\Delta u\in L^2$ must be considered in the distributional sense. Attached image.

[image]

Comment: How do you define $\Delta u$ for $u\in L^2$? As distribution?

Comment: That is my other question. Now I have just seen that it must be considered in the sense of distributions. I just looked at it in Barry Simon's book II (I'm trying to prove it directly anyway)

Comment: In question 1, it seems that you are trying to check if $u\in L^2$. You don't need to do that, it's the assumption that $u\in L^2$. Also, in question 2, $\Delta$ is unbounded so $\| \Delta\|$ is infinte.

Comment: I suggest you write down precisely the definition of "$\Delta f \in L^2$" for any $f$, and try to check why $\Delta u \in L^2$.

Comment: Another doubt arose. What does it mean that a function $f$ is in $L^2$ in the sense of distributions? I know that any function $f$ in $L^p$ can be identified with a distribution $T_f\varphi=\int f\varphi$ with $\varphi$ test function. Does this mean that $T_f$ is in $L^2$ (in the classical sense)?

Comment: Please @eraldcoil could give me the book from which you take the Laplacian

Comment: @Ryo II: Fourier Analysis, Self-Adjointness
Volume 2
By Michael Reed, Barry Simon · 1975

Comment: Thank you @eraldcoil.